# how to find out how long the last DBCC checkdb took to complete?

Tags: sql-server, logs, dbcc-checkdb, trace, automation

In most of my servers I have [dbcc checkdb scheduled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182108/22336) to run.

I can get the last known good DBCC Checkdb through [DBCC DBINFO()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/153204/22336).

I can [read the tracks left on the sql server log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/) and I get something like the picture below:

[image]

Or I can run the following script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#MAINT') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #maint

CREATE TABLE #maint (Results varchar(255) NULL)
INSERT INTO #maint(Results) EXEC('master..xp_cmdshell ''sqlcmd -E -Q"dbcc checkdb([my_database])"''')

select * from #maint
```

and get something like this:
[image]

I could also have a look at [the default trace.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/22336)

what am I after?

How to find out **how long did it take to run dbcc checkdb the last time**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is scheduled, then getting it from the SQL Agent job's [runtime duration](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/job-run-duration) is an option.

And if you're using [Ola's solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) (which I'd recommend) then his `dbo.CommandLog` table has `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns for all the actions it performs, including DBCC work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly

`EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'dbcc'` will give you the raw data you want.

To neaten it up you could use something like

```
DECLARE @tempLog as Table (logdate datetime, theSpid varchar(10), theText varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @tempLog  EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'dbcc'
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(thetext,CHARINDEX('(',theText) + 1,(CHARINDEX(')',theText)+LEN(')'))-CHARINDEX('(', theText) - 2) as theDatabase,
SUBSTRING(thetext,CHARINDEX('Elapsed Time:',theText),(CHARINDEX('seconds',theText)+LEN('seconds'))-CHARINDEX('Elapsed time: ', theText)) as DBBC_CheckDB_Time
FROM @tempLog
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This does not work for me. I ran DBCC check 3 hours ago, and this returns nothing.  I think it only works if there is an error..

Comment: @JamesJenkins if you run `dbcc checkdb` with `WITH NO_INFOMSGS` parameter it does not write to the log.

Comment: I figured out what happened. on my test system I had cycled the logs a minute after I completed the DBCC checkdb, This code is only checking the active log file.  I ran `DBCC checkdb` a second time and this code works great.